# How do I configure Apache NiFi nifi.web.proxy.host when running in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, apache-nifi

I have started Apache NiFi in a container successfully with the command

```
docker run --name nifi -p 9090:9090 -d -e NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT='9090' apache/nifi:latest
```

and can connect to the UI on `http://localhost:9090/nifi` - however, my company only allows HTTPS connections between subnets and so I am using Nginx to reverse proxy the https calls to the NiFi container with the following config:

```
location /nifi/ {
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme "https";
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost "mercury-dev";
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort "443";
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath "/nifi/";
    proxy_pass http://mercury-dev:9090/nifi/;
}
location /nifi-docs/ {
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme "https";
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost "mercury-dev";
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort "443";
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath "/nifi-docs/";
    proxy_pass http://mercury-dev:9090/nifi-docs/;
}
location /nifi-api/ {
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme "https";
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost "mercury-dev";
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort "443";
    proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath "/nifi-api/";
    proxy_pass http://mercury-dev:9090/nifi-api/;
}
```

When I browse to `https://mercury-dev/nifi` from a remote machine, the NiFi UI starts to load, and then fails.  The on-screen error says `An unexpected error has occurred. Please check the logs for additional details.` and the Chrome developer console reports:

```
/nifi-api/access/kerberos:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict)
/nifi-api/access/oidc/exchange:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict)
/nifi-api/flow/about:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
/nifi-api/flow/process-groups/root:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

When I log into the container and look at the log files, I see a number of errors saying, for example `ERROR [NiFi Web Server-21] org.apache.nifi.web.util.WebUtils The provided context path [/nifi-api] was not whitelisted`

I have found references in the [NiFi documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.3.0/nifi-configuration-best-practices/content/proxy_configuration.html) to whitelisting the host and content using the `nifi.web.proxy.host` and `nifi.web.proxy.context.path` properties, but I can't find description of how to do it.

- Within the container there is no editor available to edit the properties file (and anyway, it's really bad practice)
- The documentation mentions setting them through the Global menu on the UI, but I see no obvious option to do this.
- I may be able to supply environment variables to the container command line, but can't find any reference to doing this and therefore what variable names to use.

How can I set these properties, or otherwise get this container running behind the HTTPS proxy?

Comment: One question - why not run NiFi with HTTPS enabled directly to avoid the need for a proxy entirely?

Comment: Thanks Andy - we run many containers and use Nginx to reverse-proxy to all of them (and load-balance in some cases) - I'd like my Nifi setup to fit into that infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker container doesn't expose all the settings you need to modify directly for this use case, so you have a few options (responding to your numbered points).

(General) It looks like you provided configurations for multiple context paths, but not the **root path** (`/`). As stated in the documentation, there are many component context paths inside the NiFi application, so when putting it behind a proxy, the root path should be proxied.

1. Correct, there is no editor in the base Docker image. You can build your own image based on this one (either with an editor or with custom properties/scripts to handle this scenario).
2. The documentation you linked to is discussing granting permission to an external proxy to relay requests. You can add the identity of the proxy as a user in NiFi to grant it permissions through the UI. This is separate from identifying the proxy service to the NiFi application (the `nifi.properties` settings). There is no way to configure those two settings you listed through the UI.
3. The current Docker [`start.sh`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-docker/dockerhub/sh/start.sh) file lists the environment variables accepted by the Docker image at this time. To add more, please submit a PR or [open a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) requesting an improvement.

Koji Kawamura has provided [example configuration](https://github.com/ijokarumawak/nifi-reverseproxy) and documentation for NiFi running behind a reverse proxy that you may be interested in.

Comment: I found the environment variables NIFI_WEB_PROXY_CONTEXT_PATH and NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST in the dockerhub documentation (https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/) and have tried them, but am still getting messages that the path "nifi" has not been whitelisted etc.  Looking at the code, these properties only take effect in a secured Nifi installation; and in the doc I linked above, the whitelisting is only required in a secured installation.  But I am running vanilla, no security, just trying to get an environment up.  So far have not been able to find any pointers to the problem or a solution.

Comment: I still think the issue is that you have not proxied the root path. What happens if you provide a single Nginx config which proxies `/` rather than 3 for `/nifi/`, `/nifi-docs/`, and `/nifi-api/`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - yes, several of the posts I've looked at (including Koji Kawamura's config) assume you can proxy the root, but in our case Nginx is proxying to many other containers, eg. /api/client is the client API container, so I haven't been able to do this until now.  I have requested a specific DNS alias to this server for Nifi - then I'll be able to setup a new server definition and proxy the root.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andy, some useful information there and I have got it working by proxying the root path.  Not ideal, but it will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to tackle proxying only `/nifi`, `/nifi-docs`, and `/nifi-api` for NiFi 1.11.4 on an Apache reverse proxy where I couldn't blindly redirect `/`. Your configuration was *almost* right.

The key is `X-ProxyContextPath`. NiFi expects that to correspond to it's *own* root context. In your case that should be `/` (because the backend NiFi process expects `/nifi`, `/nifi-api`, etc.).

If you were trying to serve things from a subpath, like say `/my/fancy/context/nifi`, then you'd set `X-ProxyContextPath` to `/my/fancy/context` as well as `nifi.web.proxy.context.path` in `nifi.properties` to be `/my/fancy/context`. Note that serving NiFi from a reverse-proxied subpath was broken in 1.11.4 and was fixed in 1.12.0 [NIFI-7758](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7558). Finally, even in 1.12.0 there is a lingering bug with LDAP login redirection when serving NiFi from a subpath [NIFI-7033](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7033).