# NiFi Disable Invalid Host Headers Check

Tags: vagrant, apache-nifi

I am running NiFi within vagrant which can change the port forwarding under the hood as needed. By default, NiFi uses port 8443. Since my port 8443 is already taken, vagrant automatically forwards the port so that guest port 8443 links to host port 2208. This part is fine for me.

The problem is this. When I try to access NiFi on my host machine, I get this error:

```
$ curl -k https://localhost:2208 #<-- Since I am on the host, I need to use 2208 and not 8443.


<h1>System Error</h1>
<h2>The request contained an invalid host header [<code>localhost:2208</code>] in the request [<code>/</code>]. Check for request manipulation or third-party intercept.</h2>
<h3>Valid host headers are [<code>empty</code>] or: <br/><code>
<ul>
  <li>127.0.0.1</li>
  <li>127.0.0.1:8443</li>
  <li>localhost</li>
  <li>localhost:8443</li>
  <li>[::1]</li>
  <li>[::1]:8443</li>
  <li>rhel8.localdomain</li>
  <li>rhel8.localdomain:8443</li>
  <li>0.0.0.0</li>
  <li>0.0.0.0:8443</li>
</ul>

</code></h3>
```

It is essentially expecting either port 8443 (which is the right port if 8443 would be available on the host) or no port listed (so 443).

The solutions online is to change the following value in nifi.properties:

```
nifi.web.https.port=2208 #by default it is set to 8443.
```

Unfortunately, form within the guest VM, it does not know where the host forwarded the port. I.e., internal to the guest VM, it is port 8443.

What would be most simple is to just disable this `Invalid Host Header` error and just allow the traffic through. So my question is **how do I disable this invalid host header check?**

*(Afterall, NiFi is username/password secured so I feel my bases are covered enough. Also this is an internal development machine and the ports can change. I don't need this level of security yet. By the time this is in production, the ports will be set in stone and I could go back to the default security...)*

Comment: with https configured there is no way to turn off hostname validator. not familiar with vagrant but if you able to set NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT environment variable before nifi/start.sh it should fix the problem.

Comment: @Rob - this is not general vagrant support. I am simply explaining that I am using vagrant and that vagrant auto-forwards ports. Moral of story: `port 8443 is being forwarded`.

Comment: @daggett - didn't the HTTP based authentication get deprecated? I will look into this idea though.

Comment: take a look at this file: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-docker/dockerhub/sh/start.sh#L53 i know it's a part of dockerized nifi but maybe you'll find some suitable solution

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to use the nifi.web.proxy.host property in nifi.properties:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#proxy_configuration

Comment: Do you know of a usage case example that shows this working? I will check it out on my own with the doc link, but just hoping for an example.

Comment: This thread might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62218588/how-do-i-configure-apache-nifi-nifi-web-proxy-host-when-running-in-a-docker-cont
I'm not familiar with Vagrant but basically you need to update nifi.properties with nifi.web.proxy.host=localhost:2208 to add this to the list of valid host headers.

Comment: Yes, it looks like setting that line in nifi.properties does the trick. If 2208 is the port, using this works `nifi.web.proxy.host=localhost:2208`